# How to use java.util.Date with new test scenarios Business Central v7.25

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I am attempting to create test cases for rules where the one of the input object's fields is a Date (java.util.Date) using version 7.25 and the new test scenarios (this works with legacy test scenarios). The editor returns the following error message:  Error message: Class java.util.Date is not supported regardless of what is entered as a value in a property row, when the scenario is run. I have not found a way around this using Date type.

Answer (score 4):

New test scenario supports for now only [java.time.LocalDate](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-4018) and not java.util.Date

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.time.LocalDate` with the new test scenario does appear to work. I tried `LocalDateTime` and this did not appear to be supported.